# PHP OOP CRUD: Weird behaviour

Tags: php, oop, crud

I am playing around, creating an OOP CRUD to do some basic tasks.

Everything is working fine, but I have found a really weird bug in my code.

I have an edit page where I pull information from the database and fill up the text inputs with the values.

For this task, I have class methods ( getTitleById($pageId) and getContentById($pageId), Please see below:

```php
<?php

if(isset($_GET['id'])){
  $pageId = $_GET['id'];

require("classes/class.page.php");
$page = new Page();
}

?>

<html>
  <head>
    <title>Edit page</title>
  </head>

  <body align="center">
    <form autocomplete="off" method="POST" action="controller.php?id=<?=$pageId?>">
      <input value="<?=$page->getTitleById($pageId);?>" type="text" name="page_title" placeholder="Page title">
      <input value="<?=$page->getContentById($pageId)?>" type="text" name="page_content" placeholder="Page content">
      <input type="submit" name="editPage" value="Edit page"/>
    </form>
    <br><br>
      <a href="index.php">Back</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is my Edit page.
Again, my class and everything is working fine but then there is this weird problem here:

```html
<input value="<?=$page->getTitleById($pageId);?>" type="text" name="page_title" placeholder="Page title">
      <input value="<?=$page->getContentById($pageId)?>" type="text" name="page_content" placeholder="Page content">
```

These are 2 input fields required to edit the page information.
When I run this, I only see the first input (page_title) for some strange reason and it completely hides my second input. ( see screenshot below )

[image]

When I fill up the value of the second input (content) with dummy text like "hello" and run it again, it works great and loads everything:

[image]

Or when I switch it ( title with dummy text, content from class method ), I get the same bug where content is showed but title hidden...

I have taken a good look at my class and do not see anything strange happening.
I'm really curious to find out what is causing this behavior?

Comment: Side note: `action="controller.php?id=<?=$pageId?>">` is vulnerable to Cross side scripting. Because you are using `$pageId = $_GET['id'];` without `htmlspecialchars()` to prevent Cross side scripting.

Comment: I appreciate the comment about security and will update it to include htmlspecialchars(), but obviously I am not going to use this in production. Just trying out the OOP method of doing this to find bugs/problems and learn about it.  Thank you.

Comment: what is the output of getTitleById method. also you didn't check if $page variable is set or not. if it not set php will throw a warning that may cause your second input hide.

Comment: also there has another error may show that call getTitleById on null something like that

Comment: The getTitleById outputs / returns the page title by selecting the row from the database with the given Page ID.

The getContentById has a similar function but selects and outputs the content with the given Page ID instead of the title.

Comment: Update:  Checking if $page variable has been set or not did not solve/change anything with my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have found my own problem:

I did say that nothing is wrong with my class, but next time I need to tone down my coding-arrogance and review everything :)

I had re-required the database class which caused a silent warning and hid the rest of my code ( the input and button ) as Shahadat Hossain Khan had pointed out.

See below:

```php
  /* pull title of page from database by ID */
    public function getTitleById($pageId)
    {
        $this->pageId = $pageId;

        require("class.database.php");
        $conn = Database::getConnection();
        $q    = "SELECT page_title FROM pages WHERE page_id = '$this->pageId'";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($q);
        $stmt->execute();

         while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
            $this->pageTitle   = $row['page_title'];
        }
      return $this->pageTitle;
    }



   /* pull content of page from database by ID */
    public function getContentById($pageId)
    {
        $this->pageId = $pageId;
        $conn = Database::getConnection();
        $q    = "SELECT page_content FROM pages WHERE page_id = '$this->pageId'";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($q);
        $stmt->execute();

         while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
            $this->pageContent   = $row['page_content'];
        }
      return $this->pageContent;
    }
```

The method "getContentById" had another "require('class.database.php')" inside it and when removed it solved my problem.